# Set LocalStorage based on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html

How would I set the value of a localstorage item based on the value of a dropdown selection?

```
   <select id="theme" onchange="">
            <option value="simple">Simple</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="blood">Blood</option>
            <option value="beige">Beige</option>
            <!-- <option value="default">Default</option> -->
            <option value="league">League</option>
            <option value="moon">Moon</option>
            <option value="night">Night</option>
            <option value="serif">Serif</option>
            <option value="sky">Sky</option>
            <option value="solarized">Solarized</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: well i was thinking something like this : localStorage.setItem("theme", themeOp); but in a function pasing the value to that function . I dont know how i would update it when its been set.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value on the change handler like this:

```
var selectTheme = document.getElementById('theme');

selectTheme.addEventListener('change', function(){
    localStorage.setItem('theme', this.value);
});
```

Or just plain

```
localStorage.setItem('theme', selectTheme.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = document.getElementById("my-select");
var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
localStorage['value'] = option;
console.log('The selected value is: ' + localStorage['value']);
```

Comment: A1rPun's version is better :) the on change is nice, and setItem is better than using localStorage['value'] = 'bla';

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for now

```
function setTheme(themeOp){
    var Themelink = document.getElementById('ppt').contentWindow.document.getElementById('theme');


var e = document.getElementById("theme");
var option = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
localStorage['value'] = option;
console.log('The selected value is: ' + localStorage['value']);

    console.log (localStorage.theme);
    if (Themelink){
        Themelink.setAttribute('href','http://myurl/css/theme/' + localStorage['value'] + '.css'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Drew, thanks for sharing your solution but it is common to do not ;) Just accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me

```
 <select id="theme" onchange="">
        <option value="simple">Simple</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="blood">Blood</option>
        <option value="beige">Beige</option>
        <!-- <option value="default">Default</option> -->
        <option value="league">League</option>
        <option value="moon">Moon</option>
        <option value="night">Night</option>
        <option value="serif">Serif</option>
        <option value="sky">Sky</option>
        <option value="solarized">Solarized</option>
    </select>
```

here jquery

```
$(function(){

    $('#theme').change(function() {
      var locationName = $('#theme option:selected').val();
      localStorage.setItem('locationName', locationName);

    });
});
```

Comment: not working please using https://jsfiddle.net to show your script example